# SSIS does not work when the ispac has been deployed using SQL Server manager

Tags: ssis

I am facing a really weird situation. I have a SSIS project  that runs smoothly in VS2015.
If I deployed the ISPAC into the server using VS2015, not problem... I run the Sql job and everything is ok.

But!!! if I use the SQL server to deploy the package... Integration Services Catalogs-->SSISDB-->ProjectName-->Projects-->right click--> deploy

When I run the sql job the SSIS app throws an error:

```
The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.
```

obviously I have clean, recompile, update, change lines, bla bla bla... and it does nos work

sql server version is 2012

VS2015

the SQL server  isdeploymentwizard.exe version is 12.0

the VS isdeploymentwizard.exe version is 14.0

Anybody knows waht is happening and how to fix it???

thanks